# Возможно ли организовать прозрачное восстановление связи посредством WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf

Необходимо реализовать прозрачное восстановление связи средствами WCF. Под "прозрачным" я подразумеваю ситуацию, при которой, в случае обрыва связи, текущий вызванный на WCF-сервисе метод не прекратит свою работу с выброшенным исключением, а в случае, если восстановление связи было удачным, нормально завершит свою работу. Возможно ли это? Может быть, необходимо создавать свой класс канала для связи с сервисом, и уже внутри методов этого класса перехватывать исключения, связанные с потерей связи, и восстанавливать её, т.о. чтобы вызывающий код "не заметил" того, что был обрыв связи? Решение, при котором мы просто создаём заново канал связи и вызываем метод еще раз мне не подходит, т.к. в контракте есть методы последующий вызов которых зависит от предыдущих. Например, методы добавления или удаления пользователей и пр.

Comment: вам скорее нужно избавиться от этого `в контракте есть методы последующий вызов которых зависит от предыдущих`, чем городить огороды с восстановлением соединения

Comment: Да, должно быть Вы правы. Возможно, проще переписать некоторые методы, чем "городить огород". Но было бы интересно узнать все же, предоставляет ли WCF такую возможность, о которой я написал в вопросе.

Comment: не знаю как там в WCF, но если иметь что то типа шедулера / выполнителя задач (например, чо то типа [этого](https://www.hangfire.io/) или что то более легковесное), то вы через сервис сможете ставить задачу на выполнение, и после этого будет абсолютно без разницы, есть у вас соединение или нет с сервером, задача сама выполнится, а клиент, при наличии соединения, может узнать статус задачи.

Comment: штатных средств для такого поведения в WCF нет.